# Find the missing digit in the sequence 0110100011111?0011000011011

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence, missing-digits

What digit would you put in place of question mark in the below sequence and why?

0110100011111**?**0011000011011

P.S. Hint: 0=1, 1=0,...

Comment: Only one digit.

Comment: Not prime: $55035419=2896601^{1}19^{1}$; $55043611=419^{1}383^{1}7^{3}$

Comment: The missing digit should be `0` or `1`. lol

Comment: @Arulkumar: We don't know that. There are 27 digits, which might suggest a grouping of 9 letters, each represented by a three-digit ternary number.

Comment: I would place a 0 - because it looks good. Don't you think you need to narrow down the puzzle a bit? As it is worded now, there is not a single clue of what would be "correct". Say "...because I wanted the number to be like Pi" or "...because I wanted the number NOT to be Pi" are equally valid!

Comment: @Arulkumar Well, there were other 26 places I could have shown missing instead, but I did not!

Comment: @JonathanAllan It does not involve any of the prime logic!

Comment: Hello! I've put this question on hold for now as too broad, because I'm not sure this question sufficiently limits the scope of possible answers. If you can find a way to rebuild this puzzle so that it has a limited number of objectively correct answers, please feel free to edit it!

Comment: @Emrakul I can add a hint, does that work?

Comment: @HiteshDholaria Hints usually aren't considered to be a part of the puzzle itself, so unfortunately it's probably going to have to be an edit to the body of the question.

Comment: @Emrakul I think you should give it a try, a hint would definitely help people figure out possible answers.

Comment: Based on the hint it doesn't matter what you put there (1 or 0) as they are all the same thing.

Comment: @gtwebb One has to think out of box to figure out why 0=1, 1=0,...!

Answer (score 2):

Might be number is

> 0

Because

> bitwise XOR operation
>
> 011 ^ 010 = 001
>
> 111 ^ 100 = 011
>
> 000 ^ 011 = 011

Comment: No, it was not intended! Moreover, in your logic I see an imbalance in the number of digits on both the sides, i.e., (3+2+1+7)=(4+3+0+3+3), which I would avoid in any case!

Comment: @Hitesh I have modified my question.

Comment: @Anjan seems correct! +1

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is too simple thought..

But I go with

> 0

because

> the parity bit is 1 and there are already 13 '1'

Comment: I rather posted this as comment, but I don't have enough rep

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the right answer!

Comment: @HiteshDholaria Ha-ha, ok, so the answer is 1 but still remains the question "why"?

Comment: @RadoslavHristov I don't know why people think only in binary, sounds like a common psychology error, though it could be a trap as well :)

Comment: @HiteshDholaria Obviously it was meant as a joke. As the base is not mentioned it might be any digit from 0 up to F (assuming you are not using some exotic notations).